# C# Asynchronous socket server, temporary stop new connections

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I have a C# Asynchronous socket server, like so:

```
private Socket _serverSocket;
_serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
_serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1234));
_serverSocket.Listen(6);
_serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnClientConnect), null);
```

I want to be able to stop new connections, without effecting existing connections, and then maybe allow new connections later. What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
_serverSocket.Close();
```

When you want to start listening again, re-create the socket, bind it, listen, and begin accepting again.

Comment: Would this terminate existing connections?